# Y-axis label clustered Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, label

I don't know what I have done wrong here that is making the y-tick labels clustered together. I am trying to set the label to the values in the set_yticklabels and I get the clustered in the bar chart. The x-axis ticks and labels work fine but the y-axis isn't.
What I am trying to achieve is to have the y-axis tick labels not clustered, hopefully someone can help.
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your math is wrong and your percentages go way up higher than 1. If thats true then its logical for your y-axis to appear clustered like that.